# $L^p$ integrability of products of Gaussian variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, lp-spaces

Gaussian variables have moments of all orders, so by Hölder's inequality the product of two Gaussian variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ has finite $L^1$-norm:

$$
\|\xi \cdot \eta\|_1 \leq \|\xi\|_2 \cdot \|\eta\|_2 < \infty.
$$

Can one strengthen this argument to show that the $L^2$-norm (or, in general, $L^p$ for $p<\infty$) is also finite?

Comment: Ok, got it, L^2 integrability should follow by Cauchy-Schwarz, at least for centered variables.

Comment: It is not the answer you are looking for, but from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html we have that the pdf of $\xi\cdot\eta$ has only logarithmic singularities, hence it belong to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for any $1\leq p < \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that $\xi\cdot\eta$ has a finite $L^p$ norm due to [Young's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality). For instance:
$$\|\xi\cdot\eta\|_p^p = \mathbb{E}[|\xi|^p\cdot|\eta|^p]\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbb{E}[|\xi|^{2p}]+\mathbb{E}[|\eta|^{2p}]\right)=\frac{\|\xi\|_{2p}^{2p}+\|\eta\|_{2p}^{2p}}{2}.$$

Comment: You're welcome ;)